# How to sort a cursor with variables in android?

Tags: android, sorting, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a `ListView` (in a `ListFrament`) with a `CursorAdapter` which shows different names of places.
At the begining, the list was sorted by this names (using ORDER_BY in my query).

Now, I have added to my item_row.xml a `TextView` containing the distance of the place from the user's position thanks to the latitude/longitude of each place and the `LocationManager`. And I would like to sort my list of places by this distance (from the nearest to the farthest).

The problem is that I calculate the distance outside the "SQL environment", and there are no methods to sort my `Cursor`/`ListView`/`Adapter`...

Any ideas ?

Comment: `Arrays.sort(locationArray)?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Example using a class A sorting by the sum of both integer fields:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class A {
    final String name;
    final int someNumber;
    final int someOtherNumber;

    A(final String name, final int a, final int b) {
        this.name = name;
        this.someNumber = a;
        this.someOtherNumber = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class YourComparator implements Comparator<A> {
    @Override
    public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        final int sumO1 = o1.someNumber + o1.someOtherNumber;
        final int sumO2 = o2.someNumber + o2.someOtherNumber;
        return (sumO1 - sumO2);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final List<A> listOfAs = new ArrayList<A>();
        listOfAs.add(new A("Three", 1, 2));
        listOfAs.add(new A("Two", 1, 1));
        listOfAs.add(new A("Ten", 3, 7));
        listOfAs.add(new A("Five", 3, 2));
        Collections.sort(listOfAs, new YourComparator());
        System.out.println(listOfAs);
    }
}
```